# What is the cause of this sudden drop in CV queue size?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, review, vote-to-close

At Sat, 30 Nov 2013 14:51:01 GMT, there was a sudden drop in the close votes review queue size from 98932 to 98314. This is about **600 questions over the course of one minute.**

It doesn't seem like a routine cleanup script. If it was, this is a *very* odd time for it to run. Also, the drop occurred over the span of a minute, so it's highly unlikely there was simply increased review activity. So, I ask: What was its cause?

> [image: drop the queue]

(yes please don't shoot me I know my freehand circle is blue) (it's actually a dark teal look again) (the source for this script I [credit to acheong87](https://superuser.com/questions/680509/simplest-setup-on-windows-to-send-http-request-get-and-apply-regex-to-response/680543#680543) (slightly modified), found through [the CV meetup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208634/so-close-vote-reviewers-next-meetup-on-friday-dec-6-900-est) post)

Raw data:

```
Epoch time  CV Size
1385822821  98932
1385822881  98932
1385822941  98932
1385823001  98932
*** 1385823061  98932
*** 1385823121  98314
    [author's note: the difference between iterations is 60 seconds]
1385823181  98314
1385823241  98314
1385823301  98314
1385823361  98314
```

Comment: The graph lies; it looks like a huge drop but it's more like 6%.

Comment: @Makoto I consider a sudden drop of 600 questions in one minute to be significant.

Comment: I don't disagree; it's just that the graph makes it seem like a lot more.

Comment: Ah, okay, yeah. The graph is somewhat exaggerated, to be fair ;]

Comment: Not 6%. **0.6%**. 6/10 of 1 percent. Expiration of close votes?

Comment: @ken Like I say, it's an awfully strange time for a cleanup script to be running. It's possible, it's just highly unlikely.

Comment: I didn't disagree with that; I disagree with the misrepresentation caused by your graph. **0.6%** is not as significant as your graphic makes it appear. The scale is vastly exaggerated. A "sudden drop" of 600 votes from ~100K is not the "falling off a cliff a long distance" your image makes it appear to be; it's more like a slight step over a crack in a sidewalk.

Comment: @Ken The graph is there to demonstrate that there was a significant drop. I'm not trying to intentionally exaggerate the drop. I'm just pointing out that there was a significant drop which was unaccounted for.

Comment: well, 600 are only so many questions as many appear within the span of ... wait, what's the horizontal scale of this graph? [loads and aims]

Comment: @Jan I've bolded it in the main text: It's 600 questions in one minute.

Comment: one minute is the horizontal resolution. What I had in mind was the width of the upward slope.

Comment: Is it ten kiloseconds (~3 hours) per tick?

Comment: @Jan A data point is taken every 60 seconds. Is this what you're asking? I'm somewhat confused.

Comment: Meight be there where multiple downvoted unanswered automatically deleted after one month.

Comment: @rekire once again, this is a weird time for a cleanup script

Comment: @rekire It would be unusual for that to occur at once; I'm pretty sure that's a daily check. It wouldn't cause a drop like this. And, yeah, as Jan points out, it's an odd time for that to run.

Comment: @Emracool I am not interested in how far apart are the individual data points (I can't discern them in the graph). Rather, I am interested in how far in time is the leftmost point of the graph from the rightmost point in the graph. By "tick", one normally means the tiny vertical line at the bottom of the graph, identifying exactly a vertical line for which the text value (label) underneath it is exactly true. Said label is useless in your graph because the labels for each tick are rounded to the same value (which only tells us the whole graph spans less than 100 megaseconds ~= 32 years)

Comment: @Jan Oh, the entire graph spans no more than a couple days, closer to one. If you'd like higher precision than that, I can give exact epoch start and stop times tomorrow when I'm at my computer again.

Comment: It's like 600 questions suddenly criend out in terror, and were suddenly silenced.

Comment: Could this be caused by an SQL server upgrade/downgrade? This would make sense if this a partial rollback to a daily backup.

Comment: Why would it be a strange time for a cleanup/expiry job? You usually don't run all your jobs at 00:00 since all the jobs running at the same time would cause unnecessary high server load. Rather you spread them out and use "random" times to avoid having several jobs run at the same time.

Comment: @sth It would be odd for Stack Exchange, because that's usually actually what happens. They set their scripts to run at a specific time.

Comment: What's the difference between the red and the black lines?

Comment: @ColeJohnson looks to be a smoothed curve of the scatter plot, but just a guess

Comment: @Cole Yep, moving average

Comment: @Emracool would I be right in assuming the little squares are tick markers every half grid "line" (which you should add in maybe a faint gray)?

Comment: I will make the graph clearer tonight.

Comment: @Emracool May I reccomend R?

Comment: @Cole I have been meaning to look into and learn R, but have not had time recently. I'll still update the graph quickly. Thanks, though!

Comment: @Cole Happy now? :P

Comment: @Emracool it's better, but there's still no unicorn.

Comment: @Emracool - I'm curious, where are you pulling this data from? (A custom script, or is there somewhere this is stored?)

Comment: @acheong87 I didn't realize it was you! I added the credit, then scrolled back down to respond and realized this was actually your script.

Comment: @Emracool - Haha, no problem. Credit wasn't necessary, but appreciated. I was only curious because I had been running that script for a week, but this being my only computer, I had holes in my data from driving/flying across the country for Thanksgiving. So I was hoping you had knowledge of some external data source. Maybe we can merge our data somehow, because I'm [missing that drop](http://i.imgur.com/JmzQr0f.png)!

Comment: @acheong87 To chat! (Easiest way to coordinate)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The cause was our weekly task that deletes [old, abandoned questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year).  Unlike our daily task, which is scheduled for 3 AM UTC, the weekly task is scheduled for anytime on Saturday (actually, it's 7 days since the last run, on a Saturday, so this will cause the time to shift).

The weekly task deleted around 600 questions that were in the close queue and then the review queue's sync task (every 5 minutes) invalidated those tasks.

This is quite common, actually, as you can see:

```
ReviewTask DeletionDate     Num Deleted
2013-11-30 14:51:31.173     625
2013-11-23 14:45:18.667     589
2013-11-16 14:35:49.823     437
```

Comment: What happens the Saturday after it deletes at 23:55? Leap Saturday?

Comment: So despite the over-stuffed appearance of the CV queue, it may be loosing 1600+ questions per month automatically?

Comment: @animuson I have faith that Kevin Montrose coded it to handle that case :)

Comment: @BillWoodger looks like it, yes.

Comment: Huh, interesting. How does the server determine the time of execution? I'm curious, as those times seem strangely spread out.

Comment: @Emracool without looking at the code, I'm assuming the service that calls the weekly task will start the next call 7 days after the end of the previous call's completion.  As that task is long running (a few minutes, at least), you can see where the starting time will increase each week.  Add to that time the 5 minute window of the review queue sync task and you could have 10 minutes of slippage each week.

Comment: @Jarrod Well cool, that makes a lot of sense. Sweet, thanks!

Comment: @JarrodDixon is there a documented list of background tasks/job/processes that are running in the network, like this one? If not, do you think it's legit to try create such list from the information that already exist in Meta, and devs (not just you personally) might add to it sometimes?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd that'd be _so_ legit ;)

Comment: Anyone else end up here because you noticed the queue dropped from ~105k yesterday (I think) to 14.2k today? Somehow it seems like over 90k items disappeared from the queue...