# Clicking "add / show xx more comment" doesn't focus on comment area

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, focus

Clicking on an `Add Comment` focuses on the comment area but when there are more than 5 comments on the post an then you get this: ([example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209511/152859))

> [image]

Clicking the "add / show 14 more comments" doesn't focus on the comment area. I finished typing my message without looking at my screen only to look at it and find out I have been wasting my time.

Can this be fixed or created if it never existed?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208901/152859

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmmm.

Thought that was fixed, but looks like it was, only for the `add comment` links.

With you in the next build - rev 2013.12.2.1187 (2013.12.2.1700 meta)

Comment: Worth to mention, opposite [feature request exists](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117351/152859). ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - specifically for mobile. Though I may have just broken that ;)

Comment: @Oded Please I thought this was supposed to be fixed by 17 : 00. Its 21:26 and its still not fixed

Comment: @Tijesunimi - You will find the revision number in the footer. As you may see, Meta has gotten the update, the other sites in the network not yet.

Comment: @Oded Oh yeah. Stupid me. I thought that number was the time of the day. Thanks!!

Comment: @Tijesunimi - No problem.