# Why is the top-bar showing me new notification of old reputation?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, notifications, top-bar

I got 27 reputation from this question [Clicking "add / show xx more comment" doesn't focus on comment area](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209612/clicking-add-show-xx-more-comment-doesnt-focus-on-comment-area) (+25 for upvoted and +2 for accept). I have been shown a +27 notification in the top-bar and I have viewed it.

Again, I noticed a new +27 notification, I checked it and it just showed me the old notification. This has happened thrice after the original notification.

(I really don't know if this bug can be reproed but I just felt it would be good to report it).

Browser : Nightly V26.0a OS : Windows 7

Comment: Just to ask the obvious, are you jumping between browser tabs a lot? Or are you seeing this when you see a notification and click back? I've noticed this on those two occasions.

Comment: Remember it happening so +1 but now I don't reset anymore to test something so can't repro. Anyway, what browser/OS?

Comment: If you keep a tab open and go back in history, this'll happen, or if you keep the tab open and have already viewed the reputation, see Dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta/208183#208183

Comment: @JMK You are right about jumping between tabs a lot. but then once I check the notification on one tab it will disappear on all other tabs. Until it shows up again on all tabs.

Comment: @Tijesunimi Yeah, what I was getting at was that this can cause you to loose track of which tabs you visited in which order, causing you to think you've seen a notification twice etc!

Comment: @JMK No that is not my case.

Comment: No bother, stating the obvious!

Comment: This happened to me last night after the question I [answered with a CW-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20339630/444991) got deleted; it caused the reputation (from the day, AFAICT) to re-show in the top-bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The popup wasn't refreshing after a real-time update previously.  Jarrod just pushed a large JS refactor that should resolve all of these cases.  Now when you get a real-time update, we'll force a reload of the associated dialog.

Comment: Was he responsible for http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209720/javascript-is-broken-on-meta

Comment: Currently, [new achievements are not loaded live](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209757/achievements-badge-continues-to-be-confused) though.

Comment: @nick: Should [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208575/new-rep-indicator-keeps-popping-up#comment665636_208575) be resolved now with the refactored code?

Comment: Also, judging by your post time and the UTC timestamp in the screenshot I posted in [my question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209757/achievements-badge-continues-to-be-confused) not all issues are resolved; I took a screenshot at 12:38 demonstrating how the achievements label was off by 295 points some time after Jarrod's new code push.

Comment: @NickCraver. I'm not sure this bug has been fixed this same thing has happened to me twice today