# JavaScript is broken on meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, javascript

I'm getting this error in Firebug:

> TypeError: l is undefined
>   https://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/Js/full.en.js?v=29537078da9e
>   Line 45

The icons in the top bar aren't clickable and I don't get tag suggestions.

Reproducible on Firefox, Chrome and IE (all latest).

Comment: I finally can post a witty comment about how JavaScript is broken as designed! (I still want my money back)

Comment: We almost had a risk of the most answered question ever on meta, glad it was fixed. *phew close call*

Comment: btw maybe it's time to think about some graceful degradation

Comment: for the record: **not** localization

Comment: @Mołot magical unicorn [just saved your precious answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/209721/revisions)! ;)

Comment: @Sklivvz [I think it was.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QPRdS.png)

Comment: Thank you, thank you mysterious Magical Unicorn ;) (and @ShaWizDowArd for telling me)

Comment: @michaelb958 that has an 's' in it. Not genuine.

Comment: @Sklivvz Oh, rats...

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd That's not an Eeeek. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/83625/115866.

Comment: @balpha I disagree, the site was totally broken... as far as I can tell, Eeeeek wasn't just for envelope but to any change/bug that is overwhelming enough. Oh well.!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd An Eeeek! post is a "Who moved my cheese" complaint about a *deliberate* change we made with which the poster disagrees. I can assure you we did not deliberately break Meta's JavaScript :)

Comment: @balpha oh, missed the "deliberate" part. All good now!

Comment: @balpha wait... so when the top bar will be replaced network wide, won't it be like Eeeeeeeek? LOTS of stuff are going to be missing all of a sudden and most likely many people won't really love it.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yes, that's a classical Eeeek.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Being fixed as we speak; should be back to working in a few minutes.

Answer (score 15):

Would convert [Mołot's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209720/javascript-is-broken-on-meta/209721#209721) to a comment, but I can't as JavaScript is broken on meta.

Would comment to that effect, but I can't for the same reason that he can't either.

But if JavaScript wasn't broken, this question wouldn't have existed in the first place.

Why am I still here?

Comment: [Seriously, why am I *still* here?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209727/how-did-javascript-is-broken-on-meta-and-my-answer-get-upvoted-while-javascrip)

Answer (score 7):

Would upvote and comment to say I have the same issue. But I can't as JavaScript is broken on meta...

Answer (score 7):

Yippie! I'd upvote if I could, but I confirmed the issue:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'klass' of undefined
```

in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/Js/full.en.js