# How did "JavaScript is broken on meta" and my answer get upvoted while JavaScript was still broken on meta?

Tags: support, meta, javascript

Would comment on my answer, but I couldn't as JavaScript was still broken on meta at the time.

Would add another answer, but I couldn't as JavaScript was still broken on meta at the time.

Therefore I'm posting a new question to ask:

How did [JavaScript is broken on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209720/javascript-is-broken-on-meta) and my answer get upvoted while JavaScript was still broken on meta?

And now that it's been fixed just as I post this question, why am I *still* here?

Comment: Mobile browser. Or someone with cached older JS.

Comment: I'm also curious.

Comment: maybe mobile app?

Comment: Maybe someone mastered the secret technique of making HTTP requests.

Comment: I must say, I noticed that

Comment: [Jon Skeet didn't vote on your answer, Jon Skeet assigned it the correct score](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts)

Comment: Technically, it's possible to manually invoke AJAX and send the proper arguments (fkey, post ID etc) but it's more likely that users just used the android app, which is not using the full.js thus wasn't affected. @Molot just checked and the mobile theme is using the same full.js so voting there didn't work too.

Comment: @Sklivvz don't you have log what actions were done via the app? :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd OK, so I was mistaken. But that's why I posted my guess as a comment, not an answer, downvote-proof ;p

Comment: @Sklivvz: I actually tried that; didn't work on iPhone. Perhaps the Android app was used.

Comment: @MartijnPieters no app for iPhone, you were just browsing the mobile theme which use the same JS for voting.  Sklivvz was indeed referring to the android app as far as I can tell. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Yes, I know how the iPhone mobile view works. The JS *could* have been different.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd "no app for iPhone"? Tell that to our iOs devs ;)

Comment: @Oded: Where do I sign up for the beta? :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters - It is a bit behind the Android app, but once it is ready for beta there will be a Meta post.

Comment: @Oded why doesn't is have alpha version like [the android's](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190200/152859)? Wasn't aware such app in under development, so thanks! :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - it is pre-alpha ;)

Comment: @Oded so "bit behind" is understatement... well, whenever it's ready I will be happy!