# Achievements label continues to be confused

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, achievements-dialog

Although the achievements label (the green reputation delta in the top bar) already has [issues with open tabs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208183), today things got a little weirder and worse.

First of all, the top bar in the open tab shows no new achievements anymore; new achievements remain ignored until you reload the page. Only after a reload or opening a new page do I see additional achievements listed.

The other problem is that the achievement box oversells me by a few hundred points from time to time. I saw this:

[image: +310, yay!]

which would have been wonderful, except I already hit the rep cap on SO and gaining 310 points in a short time period without any answers on bountied questions is unlikely. And indeed, when opening the dropdown, I see:

[image: Oh, just +15 then]

I had gained an accept on a SO answer, nothing more. The +310 doesn't quite add up there, I gained 375 in total so far, across the network (the -5 on programmers is an unaccept plus an answer upvote). +310 is what I gained after 10:02 UTC, the point at which I had gained the first 65. I have certainly opened the dropdown in the intervening 2 hours and 36 minutes, which is also why the next line below the `+15` accept score is not highlighted.

Update:

The label was once more confused, after I received an accept followed by an un-accept as the OP tried to award the accepted answer mark to multiple answers:

[image: +440 would be nice..]

Again, the update did not come in 'live' but only after I opened a new page, and again the score is 65 points off from the total for today, so far.

Comment: Related: [new-rep-indicator-keeps-popping-up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208575/)

Comment: @juergend: Certainly related, but I didn't delete anything. Perhaps there was an accept plus unaccept, or upvote then vote retract.

Comment: I hope [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208575/new-rep-indicator-keeps-popping-up#comment665636_208575) is coming soon.

Comment: @juergend: I quite agree; I do hope the refactor solves the open-tab issues as well (open the achievements once and the drop-down won't be refreshed on future achievement changes).

Comment: @juergend I think that one is live already: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209735/167646

Comment: "badge" is confusing in this context. But I can't think of a really proper word.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: It's the term used in OS X and iOS for adding counts to the program icon. The red unread messages count on your Mail app is called a badge.

Comment: @MartijnPieters oh, I see... but still, "badge" is too deeply recognized as one of [these](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) in Stack Exchange, kind of "reserved word" in my opinion. :(

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: I know, I'd love to see a better term; 'label' doesn't quite sound right, but perhaps that's the better term.

Comment: The subtab in the MultiCollider was previously termed "notifications" so I think that achievements "notification" seems to fit. The use of badge was a little offsetting.

Comment: @TravisJ: 'notification' is not quite right either. Switched to using `label` for now.

Comment: Oh, I was just about to report this bug.  Observing it as well.

Comment: We are pushing fixes for these things throughout the day today. There are a number of edge case things that we are fixing by moving to an object model in the JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was finally resolved in the last build.  If you're curious, [you can see the details/root cause of the issue here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211537/135201).