# Notification of Achievements bug returns...?

Tags: bug, reputation, top-bar, achievements-dialog

The answer of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209757/achievements-label-continues-to-be-confused) says that

> The bug (which refers to the total score of the achievement points being wrong) has been resolved in the last build.

But the following picture taken on 2014-12-21,11:42 by myself clearly shows that the bug is back.

[image: See this picture!]

Comment: Sorry, can't see any bug here. You Got net of +24 today and +14 since you last clicked the icon. This got nothing to do with the other bug report. (the number in green square is not showing daily gain, it's being reset only when you click it)

Comment: @ShadowWizard It only resets when you click it?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am very sure. Last post was about a day ago.

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493: yes, it only resets when you click it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Regarding your first comment, I don't see a way in counting +14 rep since my last click. Can you show me...? The three highlighted notifications are new, meaning that I haven't seen them yet and reseted them, so how can that make +14?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't seem a bug to me. I think this is the order of events that caused this:

- You gained +10 reputation on an answer;
- You have hit the achievements indicator. Counter reset;
- You got two suggested edits approved;
- You gained another +10 on your first answer.

The count you see is of the last three (from the moment you hit the achievements indicator). 2 + 2 + 10 = 14.

Since the two upvotes occurred on the same day, their total score is shown, not the gain from the remaining upvote (the one you didn't see yet).

This means the +20 is highlighted, while you didn't see just 10 of those points.

Comment: Ah ha. That must be it -- I DID receive another up vote! Thank you!