# Does the close vote aging script run twice on Saturdays?

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close

I'm a regular [close vote queue handler](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) and for that reason interested in the close vote queue size. (the size itself is fine/too high/too low/depressing/suicidal/whatever: we **don't** need another duplicate discussion on that)

Thanks to [hichris123](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/237685/hichris123) (with support of [Undo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/215468/undo)) we have a [two week window](http://hichris.erwaysoftware.com/) on a Close Vote Queue Graph.

As you can see every day around [03:00 UTC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/213996/158100) the close vote queue drops as explained in [How do close votes age away?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166124/158100)

However, at 16:00 UTC on Saturday it looks like the aging script is run as well.

Does this happen and what is the reason behind it?

Comment: You have to get everything cleaned and pressed ready for Sunday services

Comment: It's a last chance for close votes to age away before [Bill the Lizard](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats) starts his week. I suspect he does this by hand.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the cause of this sudden drop in CV queue size?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209511/what-is-the-cause-of-this-sudden-drop-in-cv-queue-size) (It's a different deleter, but the target set intersects with the close vote queue.)